# Execute script after installation in izpack

Tags: xml, jboss, executable-jar, izpack

I have made jar file which contanins jboss and I want to start my web application when jar extracts and installed completly on my machine. where should i write script or code or xml tag in izpack so that after installing the application standalone.sh run automatically and my jboss run in the background  and my application deployed successfully

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this thread as i just did:

You can include an "executable" element in your install "pack" element which will execute as custom script:
[izpack documentation](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Marking+files+for+execution)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `ProcessPanel.Spec.xml` file for the IzPack Process Panel. Look [here](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491734/Process+Panel) for the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<executable>` tags in your pack definitions
to specify which files are executables.  The key is
to have `stage="postinstall"` attribute so izpack executes
the file after installation is complete and to set `keep="true"` so izpack does not remove it.

For example:

```
<executable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/bin/some-secript"
                 os="unix" stage="postinstall" failure="warn" keep="true"/>
```

[documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#executable-mark-file-executable-or-execute-it)