# how to make installer for java application

Tags: java, installation

i want to make installer or setup for my java applicatioin. I also want to set classpath and hit one database insert query on database during installation. Is there any open source tool which can perform my these task. thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IzPack](http://izpack.org). It's open source and very complete.
Regarding the query you can do it in Java using the IZPack API for [CustomActions](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#custom-actions-at-installing-time) or create an script and launch it at installation time ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721717/execute-script-after-installation-in-izpack))

Answer (score 0):

This link gives a list of opensource installers for java applications:

http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators

You can use IzPack or Install4j or VAInstall

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Here is the link of some of the installers :`

[1.JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications. It makes java deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any installed Java VM by itself.

[2.Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables. The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like the initial/max heap size. The wrapper also provides better user experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash screen, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be found.

[3.JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

JexePack is a command line tool (great for automated scripting) that allows you to package your Java application (class files), optionally along with its resources (like GIF/JPG/TXT/etc), into a single compressed 32-bit Windows EXE, which runs using Sun's Java Runtime Environment. Both console and windowed applications are supported.